# invalid character 'd' looking for beginning of value

Tags: python, go

I send some data to the server using python and use json.dumps() while sending the data.

```
data = {
          'reason': 'invalid', 
          'dtype':   120, 
          'id':      708, 
          'scene':   'external_vender'
      }
send the data as json.dumps(data)
```

but while reading the data at the server-side using Go, I am getting following error. Does anyone know what meybe the possible cause of this issue?

unmarshal err=invalid character 'd' looking for beginning of value

```
type Response struct {
    id       int64     `json:"id"`
    dtype    int32     `json:"type"`
    reason   string    `json:"reason"`
    scene    string    `json:"scene"`
}
var response Response
err := json.Unmarshal(Data, &response)
```

Comment: Show us the JSON that the Go server gets. Also show us the code that tries to parse it. Aim for a [mcve].

Comment: Please edit the question and not post these in comments. The text you posted is not valid JSON, and `encoding/json` is meant to process valid JSON.

Comment: Please post what's in `Data` (e.g. `fmt.Println(Data)`). Most likely it's invalid JSON which means you can't process it as-is with `encoding/json`.

Answer (score 1):

json.Unmarshall only works on fields with capital letters.

Change this:

```
type Response struct {
    id       int64     `json:”id”`
    dtype    int32     `json:”dtype”`
    reason   string    `json:”reason”`
    scene    string    `json:”scene”`
}
```

To this:

```
type Response struct {
    Id       int64     `json:"id"`
    Dtype    int32     `json:"dtype"`
    Reason   string    `json:"reason"`
    Scene    string    `json:"scene"`
}
```

That may not be your only error - as the `invalid character 'd' looking for beginning of value` implies some other parsing error.  Trying printing out `Data` before calling Unmarhsall to see if it looks like valid json.